# Add description to custom plugin setting

Tags: options, settings-api, description

Using `add_settings_field();` i am able to add my custom setting:

```
add_settings_field('AUTOPLAY', 'Auto Play', 'printAutoPlayCheckbox', 'my_settings');


function printAutoPlayCheckbox()
{
   $id = 'AUTOPLAY';
   $name = 'my_settings' . "[$id]";
   $options = get_option('my_settings');
   echo '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $name . '" ' . checked(1, isset($options[$id]), false) . '" />';
}
```

[image]

Now i want to add a short description of this setting, something like that:

[image]

How can i do that? I couldn't find it in the WordPress [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_field/).

Comment: There's no code in your question, can you edit your question to include it? This is not something I've seen in standard WordPress APIs, and the styling does not appear to be normal either

Comment: Added some code

Comment: I had to edit the code to prevent a PHP Fatal syntax error. I did se that there are strings with embedded PHP variables, and no escaping functions are being used, which are both security concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen this type of *title* settings layout in the admin pages, so it seems you're parting away from it.

Otherwise note that the *title* field of `add_settings_field()` is [unescaped](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1730), so in theory one could add some HTML code for new title layout.

Usually the description is added to the input field.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it